# Calculate with filter but ignore existing filters

Tags: dax

I have DAX measure that looks as follows:

```
61 to 90 Days = CALCULATE(Sum(AccountsPayableDocument[DocumentBalance]), AgingBucket2[BucketId] = 4).
```

I want this measure to ignore any existing filters in place set by a slicer and just use the filter specified. I know this can be done, and I've seen it done before on videos, but can't, at the moment, remember out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `ALL` function is for. It removes any filters on the table or column specified inside the parentheses.

```
61 to 90 Days =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(AccountsPayableDocument[DocumentBalance]),
    ALL(AccountsPayableDocument),
    AgingBucket2[BucketId] = 4
)
```