# Is there a way when using the slicer in power bi that I get the associated value from other column but at their max count rather than filtered count?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

Though I want the Sport column to be associated when corresponding ID is selected, I do not want the count to filter. I want the count to remain at Max when associated with their respective corresponding ID.

```
ID|    Sport| 
 1 Basketball          
 2 Basketball          
 1 Basketball          
 2 Basketball          
 3 Tennis              
 3 Tennis              
 4 Tennis
 4 Tennis
 5 Baseball
 5 Baseball
 5 Baseball
 6 Baseball
```

Normally if I use a slicer and filter at ID 1, then Basketball would be 2.If I filter by 5, Baseball would be 3.

Is there a way to keep Basketball, Baseball, or Tennis at their max count. For example if I select slicer = 1 instead of Basketball =2 i get Basketball =4.

If I select ID 3 in the slicer I get 4 for Tennis. If I select ID 4 I get 4 for tennis.
If I select 5 in the slicer I get 4 for Baseball as opposed to the standard way a slicer works I get a filter of 2 for Baseball.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate with filter but ignore existing filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53133861/calculate-with-filter-but-ignore-existing-filters)

Comment: I don't understand the `AgingBucket2[BucketId] = 4` portion. Do i need to add it for this?

Comment: Create measure to count occurrences of sport; [Mesure] = calculate(countrows('YourTable'), ALL('YourTable'[Id]))

ALL can ignore a filter contex
https://dax.guide/all/

Comment: I'm getting just the stagnant full count not the stagnant max for corresponding sport. For example if I select 1 in slicer I should get 4 for basketball instead i'm getting 12 for the row count for each slicer selection.